# jquery validation on blur on all input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I trying to use form validation when a user leaves the text form.
this code is actually run as I wanted but, the problem is I cannot validate specific form I input. when I leave form name, the form number also showing an error before I have a chance to input on it.

How can I split the error message on every input into the global function when the user leaves the form text?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').on('blur', function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
      nama ($('#nama').val());
      no($('#nomor').val());
    });
  });
  
  
  function nama(myname){
    if(!myname){
    $('<span>name cannot be empty</span>').insertAfter('#nama'); 
    }
  }
  
  
    function no(mynomor){
    if(!mynomor){
      $('<span>number cannot be empty</span>').insertAfter('#nomor');  
    }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>name</p>
<input type="text" id='nama'>
<br>
<p>number</p>
<input type="text" id='nomor'>
```

Comment: so you have multiple forms with same input and same id?

Comment: `$(this).each()` makes little sense, `$(this)` refers to only the one input field the blur event occurred upon here, so there is no need to “loop over” it in the first place. And if you don’t want both validations to happen at the same time, well then you must not _call_ both of those functions at the same time. So you will either need to assign individual event handlers to your fields, or figure out a way to differentiate between your fields inside your one, common handler function (for example by checking the content of their `id` attribute in this case.)

Comment: when I wrote the code I just thought that it can be achieved by looping, because it would be wasted if I wrote one code one validation by triggering ID. I should think that I have to use common think to handle and maybe it can be achive by traversing the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to let the error message in the HTML, but not being displayed, then when the `blur` events occur, you check to see if the field is empty, if it is, then get the element with the error message and show it.

I created a function that will be called by every `input[type=text]` when blur occurs, that function will check/validate the field

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').on('blur', function(){
    validateField(this)
  });
  
  function validateField(field){
    let value = field.value;
    if (value.trim().length < 1 || value === null){
      $(field).siblings(".invalid-msg").removeClass("not-error").addClass("error-show")
    }else{
      $(field).siblings(".invalid-msg").removeClass("error-show").addClass("not-error")
    }
  }
  
});
```

```css
.error-show{
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

.not-error{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>name</p>
  <input type="text" id='nama'> <span class="not-error invalid-msg">Name can't be empty</span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <p>number</p>
  <input type="text" id='nomor'> <span class="not-error invalid-msg">Number can't be empty</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, surely there so many approaches this thing can be done, it never thought my mind that using 'this' can bring selector into argumens function.It was briliant but, the only thing using this it will be adding more structure

Comment: you are not obligated to add more structure, but adding it, you turn your code more robust, being able to control better the elements

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code to achieve that hide show by using the error message `span` in the HTML itself and then selecting the `span` element based on the `input` element `id`. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').on('blur', function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    if (e.target.value) {
      $('#' + id + 'span').hide();

    } else {
      $('#' + id + 'span').show();

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error-span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>name</p>
<input type="text" id='nama'>
<span id='namaspan' class='error-span'>name cannot be empty</span>
<br>
<p>number</p>
<input type="text" id='nomor'>
<span id='nomorspan' class='error-span'>number cannot be empty</span>
```

Comment: thank for your suggestion, I should be notice that I can get value by id then pass the value into condition. thats was brilian, thank you

Comment: @WiddestoYudistiro you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.